# How to access dynamically created checkbox in another button code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project, initially, i am submitting which year,division and subject (of students) i want to access in the student database. Once i click the submit button, dynamic checkboxes are created according to the query submited above.
However i am facing a problem while eventhandling these checkboxes to update the attendance of students for the above submited subject!
please help!
    code :
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
      using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Xml.Linq;

```
namespace iso_generator
{
public partial class attendance : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    CheckBox cb1;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da;
    System.Data.DataSet ds;

    static int inc = -1;
    static int maxRows;
   // static int maxRows1;



   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\ISO\\DB\\db1.mdb";
        con.Open();


        string division = ddlDivision.Text;
        string year = ddlYear.Text;
        string subj = ddlSubject.Text;

        String query = "select * from student " +
            "where syear = '" + year + "' AND div ='" + division + "' order by roll";

        da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "student");
        maxRows = ds.Tables["student"].Rows.Count;





    }

    protected void ATTENDANCE_SUBMIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Create a new HtmlTable object.
        HtmlTable table1 = new HtmlTable();
        table1.ID = ("YOURID");

        // Set the table's formatting-related properties.
        table1.Border = 1;
        table1.CellPadding = 1;
        table1.CellSpacing = 1;
        table1.BorderColor = "red";

        // Start adding content to the table.
        HtmlTableRow row;
        HtmlTableCell cell;
        int i = 0;


        for (int m = 0; m < 10; m++)
        {
            // Create a new row and set its background color.
            row = new HtmlTableRow();
            row.BgColor = "lightyellow";
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                if (i < maxRows)
                {
                    // Create a cell and set its text.
                    DataRow dRow;
                    dRow = ds.Tables["student"].Rows[i];

                    cb1 = new CheckBox();
              cb1.Checked = false;

                    cb1.ID = "" + dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();   //setting gr no to chechked box id//
                    cb1.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString() + " : " +
                        dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    cb1.Height = 50;
                    cb1.AutoPostBack = true;
                    cb1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler
                                       (cb1_CheckedChanged);

                    cell = new HtmlTableCell();

                    cell.Controls.Add(cb1);
                    // Add the cell to the current row.
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                    i++;
                }

            }

            // Add the row to the table.
            table1.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        // Add the table to the page.
        //this.Controls.Add(table1);

        form1.Controls.Add(table1);




    }

    protected void cb1_CheckedChanged
            (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string marks;
        if (cb1.Checked)
        {

            DataRow drow = ds.Tables["student"].Rows[0];  //go  to 1st row of database//
            string variable = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString(); //get 1st student GR_NO value in variable//

            for (inc = 0; variable != cb1.ID; inc++)  //scan from 1st student GR_NO till the NON-CHECKED chckbox student GR_NO IN DATABASE//
            {
                drow = ds.Tables["student"].Rows[inc];
                variable = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
            }

            if (ddlSubject.Text == "SUB1")
            {
                marks = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString();   //7TH COLUMN IN DATABASE IS SUBJECT1 COLUMN//
                marks = marks + 1;                //INCREMENT THE ATTENDANCE BY 1//
                drow[7] = marks;
            }


        }

    }
```

}

Comment: The error is pretty clear: cb1 is null when you try to access it.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't even need to be made dynamically, just hide it. **Edit** or just disable save button until it can be used

Answer (score 0):

That is the behaviour. When there is postback, all variables are reset and reassigned.

EDIT: Ok the problem is that cb1 is just a variable. You use it every time you dynamically create a checkbox which means you can't access each checkbox by simply referring to cb1. You need to find the control by the ID you assigned to it OR with the same logic used to create it. I would advise giving your table an ID that you can use to retrieve it in subsequent postbacks.

```
HtmlTable table = Form1.FindControl("YourID");
for (int m = 0; m < table.Rows.Count; m++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < table.Rows[m].Cells.Count, x++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < table.Rows[m].Cells[x].Controls.Count; c++)
        {
            if (typeof(table.Rows[m].Cells[x].Controls[c]) == typeof(CheckBox))
            {
                if (((CheckBox)table.Rows[m].Cells[x].Controls[c]).Checked)
                {     
                    //Your logic here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's important when you take this approach is to have a way of identifying the learner who's checkbox you are currently busy with in order to update the DB. Please let me know if you need any clarity on anything.

Comment: initially, there is a submit button where i have to entire the division of students for whom im suppose to update the attendance. so based on the number of students in that division, that many number of checkboxes are created dynamically!!

Comment: once the submit button is clicked, dynamic checkboxes are created. then after checking the required checkboxes, save button is clicked to update the non checked checkboxes.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this or are you still struggling?

Comment: Ok the problem is that cb1 is just a variable. You use it every time you dynamically create a checkbox which means you can't access it by simply referring to cb1. You need to find the control by the ID you assigned to it. You will have to use very similar logic to how you created the checkboxes to read them. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thankyou for your help.it shows an error  for the following statement :                                                           HtmlTable table = Form1.FindControl("YourID");        Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable'.\\ An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)\\ 
                                 if (typeof(table.Rows[m].Cells[x].Controls[c]) == typeof(CheckBox)) \\Error 2 The type or namespace name 'table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)\\

Comment: can i use event handling instead?

Comment: i have tried using event handling. i hav updated my code. howeve there r no errors bt aso its not working properly. pls help !!

Comment: There are a quite a few issues here. 1. Unless you're expecting only 1 user on the site at a time you should not be using static variables to store your max rows. It will lead to headaches when you introduce other users. Try using normal variables for that. 2. Your code to create the checkboxes is in a button click event. Once the checkboxes are showing and you click on one of them they will disappear as they won't be created again because the code that creates them only gets called on a button click event.

Comment: 3. You're still trying to access cb1 in the CheckedChanged event despite the fact that at that point it's still not pointing to anything. You have to find the control first before you can do anything with it. Remember, you have created a whole load of checkboxes using the variable cb1 so without assigning the checkbox you want to it you can't do anything using it. 
Have you tried binding your data to a checkboxlist rather than trying to create individual checkboxes for each item?

Comment: There is too much work on here to fix this code. If I were you I'd start again because I think it will take you more time to fix than to redesign. With the right design and using the correct tools what you want to do could end up being quite straightforward for you. Good luck!